# How can i send the results of a for loop in a single discord message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to print a list of values from a dictionary in a way similiar to what a `for` loop can print. So far, i've been able to do so making a `for` loop of `ctx.send(v)`, but it sends the results in different discord messages.

```py
@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
    await ctx.send("List of guests:")
    for v in guests.values():
        await ctx.send(v)
```

Is there a way to print the list in a single discord message? ctx.send accepts only strings, and even f strings didn't help. For the record: i want each value in a separate line, without the "", and without any text suggesting that's a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's not good to use `list` as name of function, cause it shadows built-in function [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Function [`send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.send) as first parameter(`content`) expect `str` value, so you can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join all values into one string and pass it into function. Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
    await ctx.send("List of guests:\n" + "\n".join(guests.values()))
```